# How do I determine which key in a dict has a child dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

Given a `uuid`, I want to find and return the *dict* that includes the `uuid` and the data associated with it. I've written a test to describe the intended outcome.

```py
def test_search_for_cat():
    cat_id = "a2c23d62-9d06-44f4-92dc-b28875173a54"
    cat_data = {
        "senior-developer": {
            "name": "senior-developer",
            "displayName": "Senior Developer",
            "uuid": "418714f8-b3bd-4ba5-b4a7-4f87717419f4",
            "mid-level-developer": {
                "name": "mid-level-developer",
                "displayName": "Mid-level Developer",
                "uuid": "a2c23d62-9d06-44f4-92dc-b28875173a54",
            },
        }
    }

    retreived_cat = search_for_cat(cat_id, cat_data)

    assert retreived_cat == {
        "name": "mid-level-developer",
        "displayName": "Mid-level Developer",
        "uuid": "a2c23d62-9d06-44f4-92dc-b28875173a54",
    }
```

I've started writing a function to search for the correct category.

```py
def search_for_cat(cat_id, cat_data):
    if isinstance(cat_data, dict):
        for slug, data in cat_data.items():
            if data["uuid"] == cat_id:
                return data
```

But I'm struggling with the recursive portion. When the `uuid` does not match the given `cat_id`, how do I find the key with a dict to pass to the recursive function?

[image]

Comment: you can use `isinstance(object,dict)` returns `True` is object is a dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. `isinstance(object,dict)` returns `True` if the *object* is *dict*.
 We have to find the dictionary which has `cat_id` as a value mapped to a key.
First check whether the given dictionary has `cat_id` as value or not using `dict.values()`. If not then iterate through values if the value is a *dictionary* repeat the above process again. If `cat_id` is present in then return your current *dictionary* that we are iterating through.

```
In [90]: cat_data
Out[90]:
{'senior-developer': {'name': 'senior-developer',
  'displayName': 'Senior Developer',
  'uuid': '418714f8-b3bd-4ba5-b4a7-4f87717419f4',
  'mid-level-developer': {'name': 'mid-level-developer',
   'displayName': 'Mid-level Developer',
   'uuid': 'a2c23d62-9d06-44f4-92dc-b28875173a54'}}}

In [91]: cat_id = "a2c23d62-9d06-44f4-92dc-b28875173a54"

In [94]: def recur(_dict,val):
    ...:     if val in _dict.values():
    ...:         return _dict
    ...:     else:
    ...:         for v in _dict.values():
    ...:             if isinstance(v,dict):
    ...:                 return recur(v,val)

In [95]: recur(cat_data,cat_id)
Out[95]:
{'name': 'mid-level-developer',
 'displayName': 'Mid-level Developer',
 'uuid': 'a2c23d62-9d06-44f4-92dc-b28875173a54'}

In [96]: retrived_cat=recur(cat_data,cat_id)

In [97]: retrived_cat
Out[97]:
{'name': 'mid-level-developer',
 'displayName': 'Mid-level Developer',
 'uuid': 'a2c23d62-9d06-44f4-92dc-b28875173a54'}
```

Comment: I implemented your solution but when I run the test, I get: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'`. What am I missing?

Comment: @RyanBrookePayne   You have to pass dictionary followed by a string to function recur . `recur(dictionary,str_to_be_searched)`.

Comment: @RyanBrookePayne It should work. I copied the dictionary you posted in the question i.e `cat_data` and I used `cat_id` which was posted by you in the question. May be you passed wrong parameters to the function.

Comment: You're right. I was using the parameters wrong. Thanks for the help. Great solution.

Comment: @RyanBrookePayne Glad my solution helped you.

Answer (score -1):

`isinstance(myObject,dict)`.

For example:

```
isinstance({},dict)
```

returns true while

```
isinstance([],dict)
```

returns False

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I'm not able to implement your suggestion as there is no context. Could you take the example I posted in my question, add your code to it, and update your answer? That will help me see what you've said in context.

Answer (score -2):

```
if is_instance(slug, _dict):
    search_for_cat_id(cat_id, _dict[slug])
```

Just add this below the return statement

Comment: fixed, just needed to find value associated to `slug` key

Comment: Where is the `_dict` parameter coming from? I don't have that in my example.

Comment: I changed `dict` to `_dict` because it's not good practice to use the '`dict`' keyword to represent a variable of type `dict`, similarly best not to call an `int` variable '`int`', because it's confusing as hell. In otherwords it is the same as your `dict` parameter.